# How to get similar visualization to R fviz_cluster function in Python?

Tags: python, classification, clustering, visualization

It looks like R has some cool visualization function for clusters that gives output like this:

[image]

The input is 2D Points and labels for them.
How can i get same visualization in Python?

Answer (score 1):

In [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) you may use [`FindClusters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindClusters.html) to identify the clusters, [`ConvexHullMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html) to calculate the convex hull of the clusters, and [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) with the [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) option and [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) to display.

First we will collect some example data from the USA [`"AdministrativeDivision"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/AdministrativeDivision.html) states.  The `"Name"` property includes the county so this is removed with [`StringDelete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringDelete.html).

```
data = Select[FreeQ[_Missing]]@EntityValue[
    EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", {"ParentRegion" -> Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]}],
    {"HomeOwnershipRate", "HealthInsuranceCoverageRate", "Name"}];
data = MapAt[StringDelete[", United States"], {All, -1}]@data;
First@data
```

> ```
> {70.7% , 85.2%, "Alabama"}
> ```

For each state we get two `"Percent"` [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) objects and the state name.

We can `FindClusters` on this list by using all but the last item in each list ([`Most`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Most.html)) for the cluster algorithm but returning the entire list ([`Identity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Identity.html)), which includes the name, as the cluster item.

```
clusters = FindClusters[Rule @@ Through[{Most, Identity}@#] & /@ data, Method -> "MeanShift"];
```

The hulls of `clusters` with `ConvexHullMesh`.

```
hulls = ConvexHullMesh /@ Map[Most] /@ clusters;
```

Then `ListPlot` `clusters` with each point `Labeled` while using `Prolog` to plot the hulls beneath the points.

```
ListPlot[
 Map[Labeled[Most@#, Last@#] &] /@ clusters,
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[110],
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
 FrameLabel -> {"HomeOwnershipRate", "HealthInsuranceCoverageRate"},
 Prolog -> {
   Opacity[.1],
   MapIndexed[
    {ColorData[110] @@ #2, 
      EdgeForm[{Thin, ColorData[110] @@ #2}], #1} &,
    hulls
    ]}
 ]
```

> [image]

The default behaviour is to automatically use [`Tooltip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html) in places where labels would overcrowd.

Hope this helps.